# JEST: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. Not working

Tags: typescript, react-native, ts-jest, babel-jest

I am trying to run jest tests with my React Native typescript app. Below is my `Package.json` file

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.12",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.10",
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": [
      "react-native",
      "@testing-library/react-native",
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect",
      "jest-styled-components",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And then this is my `babel.config.js` file.
I have tried all the options I have found on the internet and I have not found an answer. It seems to be a problem with the ECMA Scripts.

I have not been able to find an answer anywhere please help.